# ActionBarActivity back button to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have problem with the back button in action bar to fragment

my code fragment:

```
public class Server extends Fragment {
View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_server, container, false);
    Button server = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.status);

    /** Button Check Status Server **/
    server.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ServerStatus.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

my code in activity:

```
public class ServerStatus extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_status);
}
}
```

My code in Fragment

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Fragment objFragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            objFragment = new Account();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new AllNews();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new Server();
            break;
        case 3:
            objFragment = new Account();
            break;
        case 4:
            objFragment = new Account();
            break;
        case 5:
            objFragment = new Account();
            break;
        case 6:
            objFragment = new About();
            break;
    }
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,objFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Every time I click the back button, the program always closes. I already tried to use:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix my program?

Comment: How do you show your fragment? Do you add it to `backstack`?

Comment: i don't know how to add it

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Concerning **cross-activity-navigation**, you should not use `startActivityForResult()` in that way. Try to use `startActivity()` instead. If you start an activity for a result, the calling activity waits for the `onActivityResult()` callback and should not be finished.

In the manifest file you should declare the fragment's activity as parent activity of `ServerStatus` to enable back navigation. You should not need NavUtils.

If you want to enable fragment navigation **within an activity**, you have to add your fragment transactions to the backstack:
`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(...).commit();`

Then you have to call `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()` in `onOptionsItemSelected()` to enable back navigation **for the action bar**:

```
@override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

You may have to override `onBackPressed()` to enable back navigation **for the back button**:

```
@override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1) {
         getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // return to previous fragment
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed(); // Exit application when no fragment is on the backstack
    }
}
```

Comment: where i add code getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(...).commit(); ?

Comment: Add it here: `// update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.container,objFragment)
            .commit();` I also edited my post.